How to selectively disable hibernate @TenantId filter in Spring Data JPA?
I'd like to use Hibernate's shared database/partitioned data approach to multitenancy, where entities are annotated with a @TenantId attribute. However, I'd like to be able to override or disable it for some queries in Spring Data JPA. Is this possible?
The context is that I'm writing an API to share data between organisations, and in some cases, I want to write queries that target another organisation's data e.g. when a user is logged in under organisation A, they should be able to query for a list of products that belongs to organisation B and which B wants to share. Something like a @DisableTenantIdFilter annotation for Spring Data JPA repository queries would be ideal!
I'm aware from the docs that raw SQL queries don't get filtered, but I wondered if there was an alternative.
